# Why is AndroidHttpClient working on Android 2.1?

Tags: android, http, android-emulator

I have a line of code in my Android app [it's part of code that downloads an image]:

```
final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
```

According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html), `AndroidHttpClient` is only available since API Level 8 (2.2)

Yet, when I run this on the 2.1 emulator, the app works perfectly without complaining. It even downloads the image successfully!

So why is this so? And does this mean I can rely on it working in production (non-emulator) environments? Or is there something special about the emulator?

Comment: This might be available in previous versions, just undocumented. You can use it, and i guess since it's now official there is no problem here. I *guess* this is reliable on all 2.1. devices - but I'd recommend testing it at least on one or two devices. But in general google stated many times "Don't use undocumented APIs, they might get removed or may change without notice".

Comment: @alextsc is there some way I can look up if it was indeed an undocumented API at the time?

Comment: Never did that to be honest. I guess you can search and download the 2.1. source *(that's should be a released version)* and check if it's there.  See [downloading](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html). I don't exactly know how to get a certain version though, always using google codesearch when i look stuff up. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `AndroidHttpClient` in production build on Android devices with OS 2.1. You can find this class in Android OS 2.1 source code [here](http://androidxref.com/2.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.java). Moreover, this class exists in source code of Android OS 1.6 - [proof](http://androidxref.com/1.6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.java). Even more, source code of this class in OS 1.6 and OS 2.1 exactly the same. So, I assume this class is safe to use in Android 2.1.

But be carefull, implementation of `AndroidHttpClient` was [slightly changed](http://androidxref.com/2.2.3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.java) in OS 2.3.x - few new methods was added, and second argument of method

```
public static AndroidHttpClient newInstance (String userAgent, Context context)
```

was changed (old second argument was `SSLClientSessionCache sessionCache`). So, if you are not using this method everything should be fine.